# How many times will each print statement be executed?

Tags: c, openmp

if the following code fragment is run on 4 processors, how many times will each print statement be executed ?

```
prinf("print # 1\n");   
#pargma omp parallel
{ 
    printf("Print #2\n");    
    #pragma omp for    
    for (i = 0 ; i < 40 ; i++) {
        printf(“Print #\n);
    }
    printf(“Print #4\n”);    
}
```

Comment: Why did you post the code like that?

Comment: If I answer that question, what do I win? - Is your compiler damaged? Why don't you try yourself?

Comment: How many times did it print when you tried it?

Comment: 0. Code does not compile.  Smart quotes are not part of C syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smells like homework and of course the code you pasted wouldn't even compile, but

- print #1 - *once*
- print #2 & #4 - *4 times*, as the block is run once on each CPU
- "print #" (in the `for`) - *40 times*, if you have `40` CPUs, once on each, if you have `4`, then 10 times on each

Is this tricky homework?

Comment: You mean, [shock!], that the OP did not try it?

Comment: Oh I just noticed the "pargma" ☺ Busted, I didn't try it either